# Find wireless network adapters in windows ce using c#

Tags: c#, networking, bluetooth, wifi, windows-ce

I need to get a list of all the network interfaces connected to my windows ce device and find if the device is Ethernet or Wireless.

I am able to read the list of devices using following function.

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static unsafe extern int GetInterfaceInfo(byte* pIfTable, out uint dwOutBufLen);
```

The function returns the network interfaces, but the issue is, for Bluetooth and Wifi Adapters the Interface type is Ethernet. I am expecting it to be Wireless.

Same behavior is seen in command prompt as well.

ipconfig command lists the Bluetooth and Wifi adapters under Ethernet.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the builtin managed classes? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MichaelCoxon. Its windows ce. I don't think there are built in managed classes.
Are you sure there are built in managed classes.